# featured content: which area does this cover

Tags: theme-development, themes

new to wp

just wonder how to get content into the center of the theme

note ive installed wp 3.9.1 
choosed the theme 2014
with child-theme and 
run the plugin fourteen colors

what makes me wonder : how can i get content to the center .

i have the

- Primary sidebar and
- content-sidebar

for the left and the right side-block

question: what / which area is covered by the "featured-content"!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be default, the Twenty Fourteen theme's Featured Content looks for posts that are tagged with "featured".  You can modify this behavior easily in the theme customizations menu at `.../wp-admin/customize.php`.

This can be customized much further inside your child theme with a modified query, customized HTML or any other edit you'd like to make in the child theme templates.

Comment: thanks alot - youre great. I am glad glad glad that you was encouraged to answer - and did not follow the other guys who did stop the thread. You are the hero!!! Keep up your great work - you guy rock!